# Having Issues with external http requests on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda

I'm using cities stored in a DynamoDB table to make calls to an external weather API to determine whether it will rain in that city on that day. It then calls a separate Lambda that uses that info to message subscribers of an SNS topic that it will rain.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'eu-west-2' });
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
const axios = require('axios');
const tableName = process.env.CITY_TABLE;
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const publishMessageLambda = process.env.PUBLISH_MESSAGE_LAMBDA_NAME;
const weatherApiKey = process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY;

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const scanParams = {
TableName: tableName,
AttributesToGet: ['city'],
};

try {
let citiesArr = await docClient.scan(scanParams).promise();

citiesArr.Items.forEach(async (cityObj) => {
  // console.log('cityObj', cityObj);
  // console.log('city', cityObj.city);
  // console.log('weatherApiKey:', weatherApiKey);
  let weatherReport = await axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json',
    params: {
      key: weatherApiKey,
      q: cityObj.city,
      days: 1,
    },
  });

  // console.log(weatherReport);

  let city = cityObj.city;

  let dailyChanceOfRain = Number(
    weatherReport.data.forecast.forecastday[0].day.daily_chance_of_rain
  );
  let totalPrecip =
    weatherReport.data.forecast.forecastday[0].day.totalprecip_mm;
  let lambdaParams = {
    FunctionName: publishMessageLambda,
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    Payload: JSON.stringify({
      body: { dailyChanceOfRain, totalPrecip, city },
    }),
  };
  console.log('dailyChanceOfRain: ', dailyChanceOfRain);
  console.log('totalPrecip: ', totalPrecip);
  if (dailyChanceOfRain > 50 && totalPrecip > 3) {
    let data = await lambda.invoke(lambdaParams).promise();
  }
  // console.log(
  //   'weatherReport: ',
  //   weatherReport.data.forecast.forecastday[0].day
  // );
});
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
}
};
```

Running the function locally produces the desired logs on the command line however when running the function on Lambda the logs involving the external http request don't show on the cold start and the logs only show up once the function has been invoked multiple times and often not together.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying a cold start fails, but subsequent calls succeed? Can you be more detailed about what this means? "the logs involving don't show up in the first invocation and all the logs only show up once the function has been invoked multiple times."

Comment: Yes sorry for the confusion. What I mean is that whenever I deploy the function through using the Serverless framework the first invocation after the deployment which would be a cold start does not produce any of the desired logs. The logs only appear in cloudWatch in subsequent invocations and often not together.

Comment: @MarkB are you able to shed any light on this it has been bugging me for days. Would really appreciate it.